# How can I test for Exception cases in FastAPI with Pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, pytest, fastapi

I am struggling to write test cases that will trigger an `Exception` within one of my FastAPI routes. I was thinking `pytest.Raises` would do what I intend, however that by itself doesn't seem to be doing what I thought it would.

Since the TestClient runs the API client pretty much separately, it makes sense that I would have this issue - that being said, I am not sure what the best practice is to ensure a high code coverage in testing.

Here is my test function:

```py
def test_function_exception():
  with pytest.raises(Exception):
    response = client.post("/")
    assert response.status_code == 400
```

and here is the barebones route that I am hitting:

```py
@router.post("/")
def my_function():
  try:
    do_something()
  except Exception as e:
    raise HTTPException(400, "failed to do something")
```

Is there anyway that I can catch this Exception without making changes to the API route? If changes are needed, what are the changes required to ensure thorough testing?

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? What _does_ happen? Your client isn't necessarily going to throw an error, just receive a 400 response.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response! To clarify whats happening - I can see I am misusing `pytest.raises` as it expects an Exception to be raised from just invoking `my_function`. Whats happening now is I am running pytest WITHOUT hitting the exception case in `my_function` - causing my code coverage to drop. How can I test for that exception?

Comment: Again the client won't raise an error, just get a 400 response, so asserting it raises is indeed inappropriate. As to how to test the error handling case that depends on `do_something` throwing an error, and there's not enough information to determine how that might happen.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That makes sense. So if you happen to know, what is generally the best practice around reaching that full coverage if some code within an Exception block seems unreachable? Changing the function code to comply with testing (for ex. optional parameters to break the function) seems janky, however I don't see any other way to intentionally break a function that's expected to work *almost* all of the time

Comment: You're testing that the 400 error gets returned - i.e. submit data that isn't valid and triggers the exception. If you can't send data that triggers the exception, how would the user trigger that exception when using the application? If the exception can't happen, why test it? (if there's something in the code internally that can trigger the exception, use a dependency override in FastAPI to trigger it)

Comment: To add to Mats answers above, you could `monkeypatch` the function `do_something()` with something that would always raise an exception. Use monkeypatch.setattr to patch the function with your desired testing behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the discussion below the question, I assembled a working example for you. Typically, if you can't logically hit your `except` block, you can ensure that the `try` block is raising an `Exception` by monkey patching the function that is tried, and replace it with something that definitely will raise an exception. In the below example, I will change the function `do_something()` that is defined in `app.py` with `replace_do_something()` that will just raise an `Exception` when called.

You can put the following files in the same folder (not a module) and try it for yourself:

File app.py:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
import pytest

app = FastAPI()


def do_something():
    return "world"


@app.get("/myroute")
async def myroute():
    try:
        text = do_something()
        return {"hello": text}
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(400, "something went wrong")
```

File test_app.py:

```py
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from app import app

client = TestClient(app)


def replace_do_something():
    raise Exception()
    return


def test_read_main(monkeypatch: pytest.MonkeyPatch):
    response = client.get("/myroute")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"hello": "world"}


def test_read_main_with_error(monkeypatch: pytest.MonkeyPatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("app.do_something", replace_do_something)
    # Here we replace any reference to do_something 
    # with replace_do_something. Note the 'app.' prefix!
    
    response = client.get("/myroute")
    assert response.status_code == 400
    assert response.json() == {"detail": "something went wrong"}
```

You can call the test_app.py file with pytest (I also have `pytest-cov` installed to demonstrate the 100% coverage):

```bash
(venv) jarro@MacBook-Pro-van-Jarro fastapi-github-issues % pytest --cov=app SO/pytestwithmock/test_app.py
===================================================== test session starts =====================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.5, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/jarro/Development/fastapi-github-issues
plugins: anyio-3.6.1, cov-3.0.0
collected 2 items                                                                                                             

SO/pytestwithmock/test_app.py ..                                                                                        [100%]

---------- coverage: platform darwin, python 3.10.5-final-0 ----------
Name                       Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------------------------
SO/pytestwithmock/app.py      13      0   100%
----------------------------------------------
TOTAL                         13      0   100%


====================================================== 2 passed in 0.19s ======================================================
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes perfect sense and should work for what I intend to do. That being said, do you know if `MonkeyPatch` is limited to functions I define within that file? It seemed like I couldn't `MonkeyPatch` an imported function but I am not sure...

Comment: In the example, I monkeypatched an imported function. You can use it to change variables, objects or even just methods of certain classes. You can read more about what it can do in the docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/monkeypatch.html